# Add Bookmark to IE8 from Link (page not opened)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, bookmarks

I can't seem to find a way to add a bookmark in IE8 from a link.

I've generated links for an inhouse project that contain the username and password. Once the URL is called they are redirected to another page.

So if they try to bookmark the link after they clicked it, they'll bookmark the wrong page.

The IE8 bookmark-manager has no "add Bookmark" function (like Chrome, Firefox,... do).

So how do you add a custom link to IE8?

(I'd like to try and avoid creating url files with instructions where to put them.)

Comment: Wanna select an answer or give feedback on additional help needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always export that bookmark from one computer and have the users import the favourite (via the file menu)

Comment: This is the only way to do it. Sadly it's not very comfortable for users.